# Google AdMob Error code (1) in random devices

Tags: android, admob

I'm getting Error code 1 when loading any ad in my android app. I read about this error and is an 'invalid request'. I checked ID and that's correct. But, this is happening in random devices, it's not working in my phone and it's working in the phone of my partner, beign connected or not to the same network. What could be happening? I don't find any solution.

Comment: Does you Phone have Google Play service installed? Even in one of my test device has this issue. Check if other apps are showing AdMob ads or not. If they are not showing then the problem is with you device and not the app.

Comment: @ciphercit Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @vegafish No...

Answer (score 0):

Their is various reason for it-
1. Unit ID is Incorrect. 
2.Ad is not loaded to id.
3.ID is new.
4.Network issue.
5.ID is not created properly.

Comment: But, how could it be working on my partner's phone being on the same network and with the same apk installed?

Comment: "ID is new" gives errorCode 0. "Network issue" gives errorCode 2.